# Typescript doesn't type PrismJS correctly when imported from prism-react-renderer

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a Typescript project that uses PrismJS for syntax highlighting in a Next.js application. While I've used Flow before, this is just about the first time I've used Typescript.

I'm using  `prism-react-renderer` for the syntax highlighting and because I needed some additional formats to be supported, I had to import the custom PrismJS instance provided as follows:

```
import Prism from "prism-react-renderer/prism"
```

However, that causes it to throw the following error on build, due to it not being able to match up the type:

```
Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'prism-react-renderer/prism'. '/home/me/Projects/myproject/node_modules/prism-react-renderer/prism/index.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I do have `@types/prismjs` installed, but because I've imported the version from `prism-react-renderer`, it's not set as that type. Is there a way to notify Typescript that this should be treated as an instance of the PrismJS type?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make Typescript aware that the type from `prism-react-renderer/prism` is of type from `prismjs`. In fact, if you compare the typings, there is a mismatch in types for `languages` as an example (see https://github.com/FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer/blob/master/index.d.ts#L45 and https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/prismjs/index.d.ts#L12). Instead I just declare a module so Typescript doesn't throw error: `declare module 'prism-react-renderer/prism';`